# Socket.io direct download and transfer of mp3 files without POSTing to another HTTP server

Tags: reactjs, file, sockets, websocket, socket.io

how can I transfer an mp3 file on socket A to socket B when I click the download button on socket B?

I dont want to store it on a separate HTTP server and send the download link. Is there a way to do it? The mp3 files are about 15mb in size